# Implement A* algorithm with C# (Understand pseudocode)

Tags: c#, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to implement the A* algorithm in C#. I have built a big graph of streets (egdes) and streetcorners (nodes) where I have coordinates like:

```
10 50 Streetname 50 70
```

Here 10 50 is one Node and has a **directed** edge (Streetname) to Node 50 70. You can find the distance between two nodes with Pythagoras.

I'm trying to follow this example: [image]

I have problems understanding line 8 and from 13 to 15. Hoping someone can tell what it means.

**Node**

```
public class Node
{
    public string name { get; private set; }                // Name of the node
    public Node parent { get; set; }                // parent to the current node
    public bool visited { get; set; }               // visited, to check if node has been vsisited

    public int x { get; set; }                      // x cordinate of the node (street corner)
    public int y { get; set; }                      // y cordinate of the node (street corner)

    public double g { get; set; }               // Distance from start to this node
    public double h { get; set; }               // Heuristic (guess) distance from this node to goal
    public double f { get; set; }               // Disstance from start + heuristic distance

    public List<Edge> neighbors = new List<Edge>();         // All succesors to node

    public Node(string name, int x, int y)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void calculate_G_Cost(Node other)
    {
        g = other.getG() + Math.Sqrt((x - other.x) * (x - other.x) + (y - other.y) * (y - other.y));
    }

    public double getG()
    {
        return g;
    }

    public double GetH()
    {
        return h;
    }
}
```

**Edge**

```
public class Edge
{
    public Node node { get; set; }
    public string streetName { get; set; }

    public Edge(Node v, string street)
    {
        node = v;
        streetName = street;
    }
}
```

**A* search**

```
public void search(Node root, Node goal)
    {
        // Open list
        SimplePriorityQueue<Node> openList = new SimplePriorityQueue<Node>();

        // Closed list
        List<Node> closedList = new List<Node>();

        // Put starting node into openList
        openList.Enqueue(root, Convert.ToSingle(root.f));

        // Inizialize currentNode object
        Node currentNode;

        while (openList.Count > 0)
        {
            currentNode = openList.Dequeue();
            currentNode.visited = true;

            if (currentNode.Equals(goal))
            {
                // Stop algorithm
                Console.WriteLine("Goal node has been found");
                break;
            }

            // Calculate g cost from current and set parent
            foreach (var neighbor in currentNode.neighbors)
            {
                neighbor.node.calculate_G_Cost(currentNode);            // Calculate G
                neighbor.node.parent = currentNode;                     // Set parent
                neighbor.node.h = 0;                                    // Calculate H
                neighbor.node.f = neighbor.node.g + neighbor.node.h;    // Calculate F


                // If neighbor node is in openList
                if (openList.Contains(neighbor.node)) {

                }

                // If neighbor node is in closedList
                if (closedList.Contains(neighbor.node))
                {

                }
            }

            closedList.Add(currentNode);
            Console.WriteLine(currentNode.name + " has been added to closeList");
        }

    }
```

I know I'm using a heuristic value of 0, which makes this a best-first-search approach, but will add my estimation later.

Comment: Have I done something wrong to be downvoted?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You say you don't understand some of the lines, and then provide your current code. What don't you understand? Which part of your code doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, there was just some parts in the example that was unclear to me, but Richard made a nice friendly explanation, so now I'm trying to solve it :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to break this down into definitions and reasoning.

> OPEN list

This is a list of nodes that needs to be processed.

The implementation shouldn't simply request the next node from this list, but instead request/remove the node with the lowest `f` score since it represents the most likely candidate that will reach the destination first (the point of A* being to traverse as few nodes as possible while still having an optimal path).

> successors

These are usually referred to as `neighbors` and represent nodes that are directly connected to the current node (taken from the open list). How these nodes are connected is up to your implementation.

> if a node with the same position as successor is in the OPEN list which has a lower f than successor, skip this successor

I think you've mixed up to separate parts of the A* algorithm here.

You should add the successor/neighbor to the OPEN list if it's not there already.

And, you should evaluate it's `G` value before assigning/replacing it. If the node already has an `G` value that's less than the newly calculated one, don't assign the G value to the node and simply move on to the next neighbor. This handles the scenario where there is more than one *path* to the same node, but the path that came before it was already more efficient.

> if a node with the same position as successor is in the CLOSED list which has a lower f than successor, skip this successor

Typically if a successor/neighbor is in the CLOSED list, you skip it.

> I know I'm using a heuristic value of 0

You really shouldn't. At the very least you should be calculating basic/naive distance from that node to the destination node/position.

I'd recommend taking a look at the pseudocode on the Wikipedia page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will take a look at it :)